# Initialize datatypes in Isabelle

Tags: types, initialization, isabelle

I read quite a lot about datatype definition in Isabelle, like for example

```
datatype_new bst  = Leaf int | Node int bst bst
```

or

```
datatype 'a list = Nil | Cons 'a "'a list"
```

However, I do not find any examples how to fill those datatypes with data, for example, if you wanted to have the list initialized with size 10 and all values 0.

Comment: Previously, you asked a precise question, and I gave a precise answer, followed by some sermonizing, which is my main way of abusing the SO format. SO is a question-answer format. You ask a question, someone attempts an answer. People need to put some work into the questions. Here, someone else did markdown for your code. Each area needs to police their own, so questions stay decent quality. Today, consider me the police, for whatever's it's worth, however obnoxious. As to `list`, I see on page 1018 and page 9 of two IsaDocs how to create an initialized list. Look around. You might find them.

Comment: @user3317019 is there a link to IsaDocs you could provide. When I look it up I can't find it, and I'm running into a similar problem as the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list with size 10 and value 0:

```
definition "lots_of_10s = Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 Nil)))))))))"
```

Comment: I`m getting inner syntax error if I try this. How would the definition be for a bst?

Comment: Can you write something like definition "bst  1::int  2::int  3::int"

Comment: `bst` is a type, not a constructor. You probably mean `Node 1 (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3))`. But I get the impression that you might want to revisit a beginners tutorial on programming in Isabelle.